# How to specify default value for date input?

Tags: html, forms, input, default

I am creating a form that allows users to edit the data on the form, and have the form's initial values show up as the default.

When I set the value as my variable, it doesn't show up. All of my other default values are showing up, for type=text and in my  dropdown, but for the date picker nothing shows up. This is how I specified the default value:

```
<td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="start_date" id="start_date" size="40" value="{{trip['start_date']}}"></td>
```

Comment: Your example isn't visible after: "This is how I specified the default value:"

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Many times when you come across something like that, try editing the question to see if the code is actually there, but not properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

what format is `trip['start_date']`? I used the value tag here and was successful, maybe you need to change the format to `yyyy-mm-dd` for that field in your context? See below for my example:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Show a Date Control</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" value='2022-07-06'>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you that was my issue, I had it formatted like 3/12/2022. Thanks!